# AngularJS and SEO

Tags: angularjs, seo

If Google created AngularJS they must have put some thought into SEO and how to crawl pages that generate dynamic content?

Do they have a solution in place for this to crawl dynamically generated HTML and if so could you please provide an example of HTML that's used, and any attributes used, that would allow Google to crawl sites developed using AngularJS.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: So why does Stack Overflow have a tag for SEO? To add it's not off topic as its regarding HTML code used to satisfy conventional SEO practices.